# How to add selected fields value as new fields in $group parameter

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I've been trying to combine two documents into a result document. Although I tried `$group` and `$project` operators I couldn't.

My example collection like the below;

```
{
    "_id"  : "55b87567c022bab41a89a477",
    "type" : "armchair",
    "price": 44.12
},
{
    "_id"  : "55b87567c022bab41a89a488",
    "type" : "table",
    "price": 86.00
},
{
    "_id"  : "55b87567c022bab41a89a499",
    "type" : "LCD TV",
    "price": 550.00
}
```

My codes;

```
Price.aggregate([
            { 
                $match: {
                    $and: [
                        { $or: [{ 'type': 'armchair' }, {'type':'table'}] }
                    ] 
                }
            }, 
            //{
            //  $group: {
            //      _id: 0, 
            //      armchairPrice: {$cond: { if: { $eq: [ "$type", "armchair" ] }, then: "$price", else: null }},
            //      tablePrice: {$cond: { if: { $eq: [ "$type", "table" ] }, then: "$price", else: null }}
            //  }
            //}, 
            {
                $project: {
                    _id: 0, 
                    armchairPrice: {$cond: { if: { $eq: [ "$type", "armchair" ] }, then: "$price", else: null }},
                    tablePrice: {$cond: { if: { $eq: [ "$type", "table" ] }, then: "$price", else: null }}
                }
            }
        ]
```

My present results;

```
[ { armchairPrice: 44.12, tablePrice: null },
  { armchairPrice: null, tablePrice: 86.00 } ]
```

However results have to be like the below;

```
{
    "_id" : 0,
    "armchairPrice": 44.12,
    "tablePrice": 86.00
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$group` is close, but you need to use an [accumulator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#accumulators) operator to identify which object in the pipeline to pull each price from. In this case, [`$max`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/#grp._S_max) does the trick as any valid price is greater than `null`:

```javascript
Price.aggregate([
    { 
        $match: {
            $and: [
                { $or: [{ 'type': 'armchair' }, {'type':'table'}] }
            ] 
        }
    }, 
    {
      $group: {
          _id: 0, 
          armchairPrice: {$max: {$cond: { 
              if: { $eq: [ "$type", "armchair" ] }, 
              then: "$price", 
              else: null }}},
          tablePrice: {$max: {$cond: { 
              if: { $eq: [ "$type", "table" ] }, 
              then: "$price", 
              else: null }}}
      }
    }
])
```

Result:

```javascript
[ {
    "_id" : 0,
    "armchairPrice" : 44.12,
    "tablePrice" : 86
 }
```

Comment: Thanx!  I've searched an operator instead of `$max` you wrote. I don't  know why I didn't try it or another accumulator operator :)